# Android databinding generated files disappears when coding

Tags: android, windows-10, android-databinding

I am facing a strange problem when Fragment*Binding files are deleted while I am writing code (all references become unresolved, generated files absent in files system) that can be fixed by clean project-> make the project but it is time-consuming.
Such behavior occurs 3-4 times per hour.
Originally I thought I might be deleted by antivirus software, but I checked that all paths related to development are in Av exceptions.
Android studio bumblebee latest updates (happened few updates before too)

Comment: I have the same issue. But it happens for me about once every 2 hours. Not sure about the cause, but should definitively check that on the Google Bug Tracker.
I want to precise, you don't really need to clean the android studio cache if it is just for the build : you can't still run build debug and works just fine.
Sometimes just through a new "sync" or another "build debug" the generated ViewBinding got resolved again.
But indeed, this might be very painful if you're looking for the suggestion about ids of that ViewBinding.

Comment: delete .idea folder and restart

Comment: @RohitKumar that does not solve problem. just regenerates files, but they canbe regenerated in simpier way

Comment: I too have ran into this problem, but a lot more infrequently. I've noticed that it has the possibility to occur when I am modifying my model classes which extend from `BaseObservable`. I've chalked it up to generation/regeneration misbehaving... but I too would love to know if there is an actionable answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was because of `gradle`, for a while i changed the `gradle` version (lower or higher should be tested) (requires invalidate cache and restart), then worked with that `gradle` for a while then changed it back and it was fixes

Comment: tried it but it did not help

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the dependencies you are using are updated to their latest version also your Gradle and Gradle Plugin are latest and compatible with each other.

Also check if you are using the latest Android Studio Bumblebee version which is

> 2021.1.1 Patch 2 Built on 17 Feb

Shortcut for clean or rebuild project :

Press Shift Key twice and then search 'clean' or 'rebuild' and press Enter